# PHP script saying request method is GET when it should be POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, .net, c#-4.0

I am building a desktop app in C#.NET 4.0 for a client still using XP. In the app, I have to contact the client's website, so I started looking into how to communicate simply with the website. Some sensitive information might have to go over the transmission, so the request method has to be POST. I've gotten the app to communicate with the website's PHP script, but I don't think it's getting sent as POST despite explicitly setting the method as such.

Here's my C#:

```
byte[] postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes
    ("name=email@address.example&password=P@$$word1234&info=$0m3R4nd0M1nF0#3|23");
IPAddress address = string.Format("https://{0}/formtest.php",
    Dns.GetHostEntry("www.myclientswebsite.com").AddressList[0]);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(new Uri(address));
request.Method = "POST";
request.Timeout = 10000;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64 rv:54.0) "
    + "Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0";
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocol) 3072;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AcceptClientCert;

using(Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
}

string answer = "";
using(WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
using(Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    answer = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
}

Console.Writeline(answer);

private void AcceptClientCert(object sender, X509Certificate cert,
                            X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
{
    return cert.GetCertHashString() == "hash string for my client's certificate.";
}
```

The reply that I get from the PHP script is just the request method plus whether or not the connection was HTTPS. The response should read "POST on", but everything I have tried comes back with "GET on". Admittedly, I know little about PHP, but I've done a pretty decent amount of research in the last couple days, and I'm pretty sure this simple script has no bugs. I could be wrong, though.

Here's my PHP:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]." ".$_SERVER["HTTPS"];
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 200 Success;");
    header("Status: 200 Success;");
    header("Content-Type: text/plain;");
    header("Connection: close;");
    ob_end_flush();
    ob_flush();
    flush();
?>
```

I spent all day trying to figure out where the issue was either in my script or in my app. Could not find the issue. I output the method to the console before I sent the request, after I sent the request, and from the script's response itself. They all should have matched with POST. The app always maintained that the request method was POST, but the script invariably said GET every time. So I decided to create an HTML form in a page on the site just to check it out, and I got the same result.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Title
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="formId" method="POST" target="_self"
          action="https://www.myclientswebsite.com/formtest.php">
            <input type="text" id="name" value="email@address.example"></input>
            <input type="password" id="password" value="P@$$word1234"></input>
            <input type="text" id="info" value="$0m3R4nd0M1nF0#3|23"></input>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById('formId').submit();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I navigate to that page in a browser, the form automatically submits, and I get the response from the PHP script, "GET on" even though the form clearly states the method as POST. Is there some behind-the-scenes magic that forces the request as GET in JavaScript, C#, or PHP? What am I missing?

**EDIT**: I'm not sure how, but all of a sudden, the HTML form started working and had the correct output. So now I'm thinking it might just be something in my C# code.

Comment: Maybe the web site is doing a redirect?  I would check the POST with a debugger like fiddler to see what the redirect chain looks like.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `<?php var_dump($_POST, $_GET, $_SERVER);  ?>`?

Comment: @BA_Webimax `$_POST` and `$_GET` both showed `array(0){}` while `$_SERVER` showed, among other server stuff, HTTPS was "on", the content type as above, the user agent as above, REQUEST_METHOD was "GET", QUERY_STRING was blank, that it is fastcgi, is Apache, uses mysql, etc.

Comment: @Meloviz You were likely seeing some sort of redirect. That would explain the empty $_POST and $_GET arrays. All redirects are GET and POST variables would get discarded.

Comment: @James and BA_Webimax You're right, thanks. I checked the access logs, and it's immediately redirecting and dropping the POST for GET. Now to figure out why that's happening. htaccess woo. Appreciate the help!